# flutter clean does not clean anything/ doesn´t show an error neither

Tags: flutter, terminal, command

I want to run `flutter clean`, but it just doesn´t clean anything.
I run the command, but the terminal doesn´t say anything, not even an error.
It just goes back to being ready to run a new command.
I need to clean the build folder, so I can build an appbundle.
If I run `flutter build appbundle` it starts to build, finishes it, says the bundle is in build>app>outputs>bundle. There isn´t something like that.
It remains the same build folder I tried to delete with `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try deleting the build folder.

Anyways, here is a tip I do when I want to generate an appbundle:

Open the Android folder as a project, then generate the appbundle same as generating an android appbundle. Even the app size will get decreased.